# Complexity O(n^(1/2) log m)

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Let n divides m-1.
There is an algorithm similar to below:

```
for k in factors of n
    for i < log(m)
```

The complexity of finding factors is O(n^(1/2)).

I think this algorithm is O(n^(1/2)log m).

But I also think this algorithm can be O(m^(1/2)log m).

Because n|(m-1), O(n^(1/2)) can approximate to O(m^(1/2)).

So the complexity of this algorithm should be O(n^(1/2)log m) or O(m^(1/2)log m)?

Comment: What do you mean by "factors"? Divisors or prime factors?

Comment: I mean divisors.

Comment: Both variants are correct, but since `O(n^(1/2)log m)` is smaller I would prefer this one.

Comment: The fact that "`n` divides `m-1`" does not mean `m-1` cannot include other factors of `n` or any function of `n`, so I would keep them separate.